# Dart- How to convert map data into form by angular dart interface?

Tags: dart, forms, angular-dart

I have a map data like following:

```
{
"RecipeID"   :"000682",
"RecipeName" :"My favaorite one",
"UpdateUser" :"Tek"
}
```

How should I convert map into form including label and text input, for example,

```
   Label (key)   :  Text Input(value)
 - RecipeID      :  _______________  
 - RecipeName    :  _______________
 - UpdateUser    :  _______________
```

I tried following method, but it seems fail.

```
<span ng-model="selectedRecipe">
  <form ng-repeat="items in selectedRecipe">
    <label>items[keys]</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="items[values]"></input>
  </form>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `selectedRecipe` is `Map<String,String>`, and to workaround [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/359), add a getter to access keys of your `Map` as `Iterable`:

```
get selectedRecipeKeys => selectedRecipe.keys;
```

And then, you can use it in `ng-repeat` this way:

```
<span ng-model="selectedRecipe">
  <form ng-repeat="key in selectedRecipeKeys">
    <label>{{key}}</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selectedRecipe[key]">
  </form>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike. But it was still fail. Is this measure workable on your case ?  Console show me: 
Class has no instance getter 'key'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'key'
Receiver: Instance of class
Arguments: []

It seems that ng-repeat cannot recognize map data.

Comment: Sorry, I had no possibility to test the answer. Looks like there is an issue at angular's github, please see updated answer. Now it's working.